# No problems logging in, but sudo gives authentication failure

Tags: sudo, authentication

So to start things off I have had a server running Ubuntu 18.04 for the last two years or so running just fine.

I was logged in to it last night copying some files to my NAS and doing a few other things without issue.

This morning when I logged in, I started getting an authentication error when trying to use sudo. The strange thing is I was able to log in fine (both through ssh and on the actual machine), but when using sudo (which uses the same password of course) it would not work. It gave me the usual 3 attempts with sorry, try again in between, and then reports that there have been 3 incorrect password attempts and kicks me back to the command line.

I restarted the machine and entered recovery mode, dropped into a root shell, and changed my password. Success! Sudo now works.

I did the upgrade to 20.04 and finished doing what I was trying to do earlier, and then logged out.

A few hours later, I logged back in and the problem is back. I simply get an incorrect password error when trying to use sudo.

I have done some research today on the subject but none of the things I have found seem to apply. Most the threads I found were very old forum posts with no solution. I did manage to find one thread from this past September that references an error in /var/log/auth.log that says:

`su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory`

I did notice that this error was present in my /var/log/auth.log file.

I have tried using pkexec as a workaround, it does not work.

I just don't understand why I am able to log in, but not use sudo as they use the exact same password.

I am not spelling the password incorrectly, using an odd keyboard layout, password doesn't contain strange non-English characters, etc.

Any thoughts on this one? Thank you in advance! :)

*EDIT*

Ok so there has been a recent development! I decided to try using a different tty to see if that helped so I hit ctrl+alt+F3 and voila, sudo works! Not only that, when I switched back to tty1, sudo still worked, and when I logged in from my laptop via ssh, sudo still worked!

Not sure if this has fixed the issue entirely though. I am going to log out of all these sessions and wait 15-20 minutes here and see if I'm able to use any sudo commands without having to do this tty trick.

*EDIT #2*

Alright so as I suspected, after logging out and waiting for the sudo "grace period" (for lack of a better term) to wear off, I logged back in and am once again getting an incorrect password error when trying to use a sudo command.

Comment: please can you add `ls -al /etc/ | grep sec`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   4 root root                 4096 Mar 23 16:33 security

Comment: `sudo cp /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/securetty /etc/`  wIred have the same entry in my auth.log but no errors in (focal)

Comment: Believe it or not, I think resetting my keyboard configuration may have solved the problem. I used "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration" and selected generic 105 key, us English, etc. The funny thing is that I didn't really change anything. I just selected what was previously highlighted. Very odd. I'm sure copying that securetty should get rid of the errors in auth.log as well but I don't think that was actually the root of the problem.