User no longer in sudoers after installing ssh
My admin account was added to sudoers and worked fine. I set up SSH and xRDP on my computer. I used the exact same username for these programs. Now when I try to sudo, it says my user is not in the sudoers list. I can switch to root, but that doesn't fix my problem.
What I think happened is that when I log in as the user, it's using my SSH login. If I'm correct, how do I log out of the SSH user if the usernames are the same. But maybe I'm wrong and something else is going on.
Also: when I try to add the user to sudoers file, it says the user is already added
EDIT:
I'm not 100% sure that it has anything to do with xRDP or SSH. I started having the issue afterwards, but it may be unrelated. Also, I don't think I created a new user, just added the existing user; but I am not sure about this either.

last comment maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325692/no-problems-logging-in-but-sudo-gives-authentication-failure

So... when you set up ssh, you created a new user account with a non-unique (i.e. same as an existing) username? How and why exactly?

@amar I tried the the last comment on that thread and it didn't work for me.

@steeldriver I'm not 100% sure if a created a new account. I probably just added the user account.

It's going to be hard to help without knowing exactly what you did - fyi on Ubuntu systems it would not be typical to add users directly to the sudoers file, it's generally done by adding them to the sudo group (which already has an entry in the file).

... if you can switch to root, then you could run pwck -r which (among other things) would tell you about any non-unique usernames

... you can also use getent group sudo to see whether one, both or neither account is currently in the sudo group

Below is some output from my terminal, with some personal info redacted... In case anyone is wondering. I logged off after running this, then logged back in, and tried to sudo, but received the same 'not in sudoer file' message.

root@a#####6:~# pwck -r
user 'lp': directory '/var/spool/lpd' does not exist
user 'news': directory '/var/spool/news' does not exist
user 'uucp': directory '/var/spool/uucp' does not exist
user 'list': directory '/var/list' does not exist
user 'irc': directory '/run/ircd' does not exist
pwck: no changes
root@a#####6:~# getent group sudo
sudo:x:27:
root@a#####6:~# adduser a######### sudo
Adding user a########' to group sudo' ...
Done.
root@a#######6:~# exit
logout
a#######@a########:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
[sudo] password for a##########:

Adding a userid to /etc/sudoers is an obsolete method of allowing sudo access, as /etc/sudoers got replaced by your installations. Rather,  add your userid to the  sudo group with (as root) adduser your_userid sudo, then logout your_userid completely and login (groups are applied by login.
